# What tools to use to visualize logical and physical query plans?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am familiar `explain()` (also WebUI). I was curious whether there are any tools that generate an image of the tree structure of the logical/physical plan before/after optimizations. That is the information returned by `explain()` as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A picture like a PNG or JPG? Never heard of one myself, but you can see the physical plan using web UI (that you've already mentioned).

The other phases of query execution are available using [TreeNode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode.scala#L76) methods which (among many methods that could help you out) give you my favorite [numberedTreeString](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode.scala#L480).

```
scala> println(q.queryExecution.analyzed.numberedTreeString)
00 Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))

scala> println(q.queryExecution.executedPlan.numberedTreeString)
00 *Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
```

You can save the output as JSON using `toJSON` or `prettyJson` to generate PNG (but I've never tried it out myself).

```
scala> println(q.queryExecution.executedPlan.prettyJson)
[ {
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec",
  "num-children" : 1,
  "child" : 0
}, {
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RangeExec",
  "num-children" : 0,
  "range" : [ {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Range",
    "num-children" : 0,
    "start" : 0,
    "end" : 5,
    "step" : 1,
    "numSlices" : 8,
    "output" : [ [ {
      "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference",
      "num-children" : 0,
      "name" : "id",
      "dataType" : "long",
      "nullable" : false,
      "metadata" : { },
      "exprId" : {
        "product-class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId",
        "id" : 0,
        "jvmId" : "cb497d01-3b90-42a7-9ebf-ebe85578f763"
      },
      "isGenerated" : false
    } ] ]
  } ]
} ]
```

Comment: does python have a similar API?

Comment: No idea. You'd be better off asking a separate question on SO.