# Spark Physical Plan false/true for Exchange partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, sql-execution-plan

```
repartitionedDF.explain
```

shows this for the physical plan

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(purchase_month#25, 10), false, [id=#6]
+- LocalTableScan [item#23, price#24, purchase_month#25]
```

I note that the false can also true in some cases.

This means? I knew it once, but have forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I believe it's referring to the `noUserSpecifiedNumPartition` variable. If you do a repartition, this Boolean variable will be `false` because you specified the number of partitions. Otherwise it's `true`. Try doing a simple `orderBy` and I think you should get `true`.

I found this out by doing

```
println(df.repartition('series).orderBy('series).queryExecution.executedPlan.prettyJson)
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242201/what-tools-to-use-to-visualize-logical-and-physical-query-plans). It gave an output of (truncated to the relevant parts only):

```
{
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec",
  "num-children" : 1,
  "outputPartitioning" : [ {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.RangePartitioning",
    "num-children" : 1,
    "ordering" : [ 0 ],
    "numPartitions" : 200
  }, {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SortOrder",
    "num-children" : 1,
    "child" : 0,
    "direction" : {
      "object" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Ascending$"
    },
    "nullOrdering" : {
      "object" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.NullsFirst$"
    },
    "sameOrderExpressions" : {
      "object" : "scala.collection.immutable.Set$EmptySet$"
    }
  }, {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference",
    "num-children" : 0,
    "name" : "series",
    "dataType" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { },
    "exprId" : {
      "product-class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId",
      "id" : 16,
      "jvmId" : "35ee1aa5-f899-4fca-a8a6-a06c3eaabe5c"
    },
    "qualifier" : [ ]
  } ],
  "child" : 0,
  "noUserSpecifiedNumPartition" : true
}, {
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec",
  "num-children" : 1,
  "outputPartitioning" : [ {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.HashPartitioning",
    "num-children" : 1,
    "expressions" : [ 0 ],
    "numPartitions" : 200
  }, {
    "class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference",
    "num-children" : 0,
    "name" : "series",
    "dataType" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { },
    "exprId" : {
      "product-class" : "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId",
      "id" : 16,
      "jvmId" : "35ee1aa5-f899-4fca-a8a6-a06c3eaabe5c"
    },
    "qualifier" : [ ]
  } ],
  "child" : 0,
  "noUserSpecifiedNumPartition" : false
}
```

where the `true` and `false` correspond nicely to the physical plan:

```
df.repartition('series).orderBy('series).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Sort [series#16 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(series#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), true, [id=#192]
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(series#16, 200), false, [id=#190]
      +- FileScan csv [series#16,timestamp#17,value#18] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/tmp/df.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<series:string,timestamp:string,value:string>
```

Comment: Just a quick question, do you know if `[...].queryExecution.executedPlan.prettyJson` it's available to pyspark?

Comment: @Kafels you can access the java object using `df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan().prettyJson()`